# No template parameters needed in boost::pool

Tags: c++, templates, boost, pool

Declaring boost::poor is something that goes as below.

```
boost::pool<> Obj();
```

I am curious how you can make a class template that needs no template parameters but only the <> ?

I tried making it as boost::pool does in pool.hpp and poolfwd.hpp.

```
template<class T>
class Fakepool { };  // pool.hpp

template<class T = int>
class Fakepool;   // boost::pool's declaration in poolfwd.hpp 

int main()
{
    Fakepool<float> a;

    Fakepool<> a2; // Can't do this with only <>
}//main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You missed a semicolon after the class declaration: `template<class T>  class Fakepool { };`

Comment: @YunHuang Thanks for correcting this. But it was just about a mistake of copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
template<class T = int>
class Fakepool { };

int main()
{
    Fakepool<float> a; // Use float

    Fakepool<> a2; // Default as int
}
```

You can also, do this (which I think is what you were thinking). The keyword here is `default template arguments`. However, in your example you defined the class *before* you declared it, which was the problem.

```
template<class T = int>
class Fakepool; 

template<class T>
class Fakepool { }; 

int main()
{
    Fakepool<float> a;

    Fakepool<> a2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I should've written my code like what you just showed to me but boost::pool is somewhat weird and looks actually like what I coded. I appreciate this.

Comment: Can you please explain why this works? Otherwise, we're left playing "spot the difference" and wondering whether the differences we find are actually relevant.

Comment: @RobKennedy: In C++ functions and templates can have default arguments, for example if you declare a function `void f(int x = 5)`, you can call it like this `f()` or specify the argument like this `f(10)`, it the same principle as above.

Comment: I know. But your answer at the time didn't say anything about that. Thank you for adding more detail.